# Combine .csv-files with text between each line

Tags: bash, shell, csv, paste

I have two (or maybe more) files:

**file1.csv**

```
dog
cats
mouse
```

**file2.csv**

```
001a
002a
003c
```

If I use `paste file1.csv file2.csv` the output is

```
dog 001a
cats    002a
mouse   003c
```

Of course I can use `paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv`

```
dog,001a
cats,002a
mouse,003c
```

But I want this **output**

```
TEXT1-dog-TEXT2-001a-TEXT3
TEXT1-cats-TEXT2-002a-TEXT3
TEXT1-mouse-TEXT2-003c-TEXT3
```

Is there a way to put multiple .csv files together with extra text before, between and after each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A KISS solution based on what you have so far:

```
paste -d, file1.csv file2.csv | awk -F, '{print "TEXT1-" $1 "-TEXT2-" $2 "-TEXT3"}'
```

or

```
paste -d, file1.csv file2.csv | awk -F, '{print "TEXT1", $1, "TEXT2", $2, "TEXT3"}' OFS=-
```

(which may be more convenient if you want to make the TEXTs variable).