# Combine .csv-files with different amount of lines

Tags: shell, awk, variable, csv, paste

[Here I asked already for a similar problem.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735118/combine-csv-files-with-text-between-each-line)

Now I have 3 .csv-files but one of them has only 1 line.

**file1.csv**

```
dog
cats
mouse
```

**file2.csv**

```
001a
002a
003c
```

**file3.csv**

```
WORD
```

The output should be

```
dog,001a,WORD
cats,002a,WORD
mouse,003c,WORD
```

One solution ([from my previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735118/combine-csv-files-with-text-between-each-line)) is:

`paste -d, file1.csv file2.csv | awk -F, '{print $1 "," $2 ",WORD"}'`

But "WORD" is here just written and not read from file3.csv.

Is there a way to tell `paste` to fill every line with file3.csv? Or maybe to save file3.csv as a variable and give it to `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another simple method:

```
$ paste  -d, file1 file2 file3 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {if(NR==1){w=$3} else {$3=w}}1'
dog,001a,WORD
cats,002a,WORD
mouse,003c,WORD
```

Comment: FWIW `{if(NR==1){w=$3} else {$3=w}}` could be written as `NR==1{w=$3} {$3=w}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ paste -d, file1.csv file2.csv |
    awk -v OFS=',' 'NR==FNR{w=$0; next} {print $0, w}' file3.csv -
dog,001a,WORD
cats,002a,WORD
mouse,003c,WORD
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `fill-down` sub-command of [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) we may fill all the empty fields with values from the immediately preceding record's corresponding field regardless of how long the files are.

The following command assumes that the data in each file is header-less CSV, and it will perform the fill-down operation on all three fields in each record:

```bash
paste -d, file1 file2 file3 | mlr -N --csv fill-down -f 1,2,3
```

Example run (note that I'm using a shorter second file):

```bash
$ cat file1
dog
cats
mouse
$ cat file2
001a
002a
$ cat file3
WORD
```

```bash
$ paste -d, file1 file2 file3
dog,001a,WORD
cats,002a,
mouse,,
```

```bash
$ paste -d, file1 file2 file3 | mlr -N --csv fill-down -f 1,2,3
dog,001a,WORD
cats,002a,WORD
mouse,002a,WORD
```

A variant which uses `paste` to create a TSV data set for Miller (by simply not setting a non-default delimiter) and which then converts the TSV to CSV utilising the `--t2c` option (a shortcut for the combination of the two options `--itsv` and `--ocsv`):

```bash
paste file1 file2 file3 | mlr -N --t2c fill-down -f 1,2,3
```